# Force of water hitting a wall ( if rebounds)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, collision

I've seen many question about water hitting a wall perpendicularly and doesn't rebound then force exerted on wall is **F=ρΑv2**
But what if the water rebounds ?
How will the solution be ?
Someone pls explain.

Comment: Hint: choose a control volume and use mass and momentum integral balance

Comment: It is advisable to use Latex (you can use $ $ )